# How should I handle private key files in Google AppEngine for service accounts?

Tags: python, security, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-firestore

I need to use a Service Account in my Google AppEngine project (call it **Home**) from another Google AppEngine Project (call it **Away**) in order to access its Firestore database. To do that, all the documentation I can find tells me to download the Service Account's private key from **Away** and store it "[in a location accessible to your application](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys)". I can't find anywhere that documents what this means, exactly.

Do I need to upload the `.json` private key file to the Google AppEngine server as part of deploying **Home**? How can I do that securely in Google AppEngine's environment? I can't find documentation anywhere about this.

Alternatively, is there a way to create a Firestore client in Python using a JSON string instead of a file? That way I can store the JSON private key in the Datastore on **Home** instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically a file "accessible to your application" in GAE means the file is part of and uploaded with the app code during deployment.

You can find an example of using the `.json` private key file in [Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests):

> If using a JSON file:
>
> ```
> from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
>
> scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']
>
> credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
>     '/path/to/keyfile.json', scopes=scopes)
> ```

The `/path/to/keyfile.json` is relative to the respective GAE service dir (the one containing the service's `.yaml` file)

Comment: This is the method we ended up using. We put our keyfiles in a `secrets/` directory that was git-ignored. It did mean that anyone who was deploying needed to make sure to download their own cert files... but we handled that by limiting who could deploy.

Comment: @dan-cornilescu or @staunch, what's the actual path once deployed? I tried `keyfile.json` and `/keyfile.json` and neither of those work.